# Sort a list in Django

Tags: python, django, sorting

I have to display a list of matches in my Django sport app. I already defined a function to have a list of all matches.
Each match as a DateTime "real_start", and I would like to sort them by that date.

This is my list of matches:

```
    matches = Match.live_matches.all()
```

I tried 
        matches.sort(key=lambda x: x.real_start, reverse=True)

but it doesn't work.

Any help would be welcome.Thanks.

Comment: That isn't a `List` of matches, it's a `QuerySet` of matches which can be sorted using Django's `QuerySet` API as @Samuele Mattiuzzo suggests. Alternatively, you can sort both lists, QuerySets (and other types of iterables) using `sort` or `sorted` as @Dogbert metntioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sort(matches, key=lambda x: x.real_start, reverse=True)
```

Comment: sort is a in-place method, i think u mean sorted(matches, key=lambda x: x.real_start, reverse=True)

Comment: Thank you. I tried, and there is no error anymore. But it does not work. It doesn't sort the matches.

Comment: Ok, I tried creating a new list: matchess = sorted(matches, key=lambda x: x.real_start, reverse=True), and it works find. Thank you. Now I would like to reverse this sorting (because it displays the match with the oldest DateTime first). Do you know how to do that?

Comment: matchess.reverse(), it works perfectly find. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

maybe a look at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#dates)?

```
Match.objects.date('real_start', 'day', order='DESC')
```

You can use this inside your live_matches function, no need for lambdas if you're sorting on a date field

Comment: `Match.live_matches.all().order_by('-real_start')` should work too